# Wizard offers shepherd boy the chance to be first wizard warrior, smuggles him to a wizard school

Tags: story-identification

Okay so I need help finding an amazing book I read way back when. It starts out as I believe a shepherd boy who has been training to accomplish his far fetched dream of becoming a knight. He ends up picking a fight with a soldier. I can't remember if/how he wins, but I think he does win by tapping into unknown magic because he wins the soldiers sword. I think the soldier refuses to give it up. Then at some point a great wizard shows up to the boys adoptive home to give him a chance to become the first wizard warrior, a warrior that can wield magic as well as a sword. They go on an adventure to the king to get permission but I think the king gets mad because the wizard smuggles the boy out of the city and to a wizard school so they can hone his magic. He has one friend, but the rest of the students hate him I think because he can't do magic at all, until one day the boy reaches his magical potential and way later in the series I think becomes this great chaos wizard warrior at war with someone/something.

I need to read it again. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! This sounds like a pretty generic fantasy tale; is there any more detail you can add? Also, can you give a range for "way back when" (i.e. when you read it or when it was published), so that we can narrow the search field a bit? For more tips on improving your question, see [our](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) [guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9336/31394) on asking good story-ID questions.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! This is good story-id, try to add when it may have been published, cover art, or any other details you can remember. This will help our experts help you. Good luck!

Comment: Sounds like one of the Order/Chaos books by L. E. Modesitt Jr. I'd have to look...

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are thinking about [Taming Fire](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11157986-taming-fire) by Aaron Pogue.  It starts out as you say, with the main character Daven challenging a soldier and winning his sword.  A wizard then stops the defeated solider from killing Daven (who used "witchcraft" during the fight).  From page 20:

> In Othin's homeland there is a tradition, Daven, that when a man loses
>   a duel his only honor is in surrending his blade.

This wizard then takes Daven to the Academy, where he is to be taught to be a wizard.

He is then taken to a wizarding academy, where he eventually learns that he has some kind of blockage.

Ultimately, he gains his power when

> he makes some kind of magical bond with a dragon

Comment: YES! That's it! Thank you so much!!!